# search compare columns sheet 1 & sheet 2 and change a cell in sheet 1

Tags: vba, excel

I really need some help.

Problem: I have a workbook with 2 worksheets. Both sheets has headers. Sheet1 is a list of account numbers in column A and the same for sheet 2 column A. Now, what I need to do is this:

- if I place a date in column AI in sheet 2 for a specific account number, then find the corresponding account number in sheet 1 and place the word "Complete" in column Y for that account.

I hope I explained this enough. Below is what I came up with so far, but got stuck:

```
Sub UpdateTBP()
Dim i
Dim j
Dim k
Dim LastRow
Dim LastRow2

LastRow = Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Sheets("TBP").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To (LastRow - 1)
  For j = 2 To (LastRow2 - 1)
    If Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("TBP").Cells(j, 1).value Then
      For k = 35 To 35
        If Sheets("TBP").Cells(j, 35) <> "" Then
          Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(i, Y).value = "Complete"
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next
Next
ThisWorkbook.Save
 End Sub
```

Comment: Did the code just not work, or you're not even sure how to do what you want to?

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or is the data appearing but wrong, or is no data showing up? Please give all the details you have.

Comment: @hypetech ...The code isn't working after the "For k = 35 to 35" statement. Before this code, I had another code developed in a similar way but it would only change the cell for that row. For an example: sheet 2 column A row 3  account number is found on sheet 1 column A row 5 but because the account number data is in row 3 column A of sheet 2, it only changed column Y of sheet 1 for row 3 and not row 5 (row 5 is the corresponding account number)

Comment: @hypetech This is the first code I developed before posting this one as explained above: Sub UpdateTBP()
Dim i
Dim LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("TBP").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Sheets("TBP").Cells(i, "AI").value <> "" And Sheets("TBP").Cells(i, "A").value = Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(i, "A").value Then
Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(i, "Y").value = "Complete"
End If
Next
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Comment: @hypetech There's no error message or anything, its just that the word "Complete" is not being filled in at all (neither the correct or incorrect cells; as if nothing is being done)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by using the following modified code:

```
Sub UpdateTBP()
Dim i
Dim j
Dim k
Dim LastRow
Dim LastRow2


LastRow = Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Sheets("TBP").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To (LastRow - 1)
  For j = 2 To (LastRow2 - 1)
    If Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("TBP").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        If Sheets("TBP").Cells(j, 35) <> "" Then
          Sheets("Portfolio").Cells(i, 25).Value = "Complete"
        End If
    End If
  Next
Next
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Please note that this will not include your last row of data as you have subtracted it out with:

```
For i = 2 To (LastRow - 1)
    For j = 2 To (LastRow2 - 1)
```

If you wish to include that last row, just use the following:

```
For i = 2 to LastRow
    For j = 2 to LastRow2
```

This includeds the previous comments I made.  I just gave it a quick test and it is working.

Comment: I have tried taking out the For k = 35 To 35 loop and even substituted the "Y" with 25 instead and was getting the same issue before I posted on here

Comment: Are you looking in Column AI or AH on the sheet TBP?

Comment: Column AI is the cell Im using to validate if the word complete should be filled in. So if the account number of sheet 2 row 3 column AI is not empty then the corresponding account number row of sheet 1 column Y should say "Complete"

Comment: @awilso11 I just posted a modified version of your code which worked for me.